# (1+)-complemented, (1+)-isomorphic copies of $L_{1}$ in dual Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

I am thinking about the following question:

Question. Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space such that for every $\epsilon>0$, the dual $X^{*}$ contains a subspace $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphic to $L_{1}[0,1]$ which is $(1+\epsilon)$-complemented in $X^{*}$. Must $X^{*}$ contain a subspace which is isometric to $L_{1}[0,1]$ and $1$-complemented in $X^{*}$ ?

I think that this question is probably false, but I do not know any counterexample. I have proved that a Banach space $X$ contains almost isometric copies of $\big(\sum\limits_{n}l^{n}_{\infty}\big)_{l_{1}}$ (that is, for every $\epsilon>0$, $X$ contains a subspace $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphic to $\big(\sum\limits_{n}l^{n}_{\infty}\big)_{l_{1}}$) if and only if, for every $\epsilon>0$, $X^{*}$ contains a subspace $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphic to $L_{1}[0,1]$ which is $(1+\epsilon)$-complemented in $X^{*}$. I do not know whether my result is useful to answer the question.

Thank you !

Comment: A <a href="https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-11/S0002-9939-02-06474-2/">paper</a> by Hagler gives an asymptotic characterization of $X$ whose dual contains $1$-complemented isometric copy of $L^1$.

Comment: Thanks, Narutaka. I know the paper by J. Hagler in 2002. But it seems not useful to my question.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood. So, it's not even clear that $X$ contains  an asymptotically isometric copy of $\ell_1$.